# ReactJS: 'initState' is not defined no-undef error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state.

I have the following code:

requests.data.js:

```
export default initState =
{
    requests: [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Completed"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        }
    ]
}
```

requests.reducer.js:

```
import initState from './requests.data';
import { CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS } from './requests.types';

export default (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

However, when I run my application, I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that `initData` is *undeclared*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

1) Export directly the value

```
export default {
    requests: [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Completed"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        }
    ]
}
```

2) Create first the variable and after that export it:

```
const initState = {
    requests: [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Completed"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        }
    ]
}
export default initState
```